# Get a confirm box on change in the div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been struggling for displaying the confirm box since a very long time. The problem is I have a drop down list div = "Module", on selecting any value in the drop down list I display the corresponding values in another div = "DivRoles". If any changes done in DivRoles on clicking any other Module in the drop down I need to save the changes and hence need to display the confirm box and save changes.

The code snippet is as follows :

```
<div id="roledef" >
        <div class="formlabel">
            <div align="right" class="label">Select Module:</div>
        </div>
      <!--- Here is my Module drop down whose id = "Module"---->
        <div class="formlabel">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Module, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.lstm, "-----Select-----")
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
         <br/>
      <!------------I display the values here in id="DivRoles"------------->
         <div id="DivRoles" align = "center" >
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserRole, new SelectList(ViewBag.lstroles, "RoleID", "RoleName", Model.UserRole), new { multiple = "multiple" })
        </div>



        <div align = "center" >
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserRole, new SelectList(ViewBag.lstroles, "RoleID", "RoleName", Model.UserRole), new { multiple = "multiple", @id = "rolesoriginal" })
        </div>

          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
             <div class="formelement">
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.multi-select.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

         </div>
```

Every time I click a value in drop down I m calling the UpdateRoles() function. So first time when I click I dont need the confirm box and also after clicking the div if no changes done I dont need the confirm box. Only if any changes done in the DivRoles tag I need to save it if the user clicks any other div.

I m trying the following jquery:

```
$('#Module').change(ifChangeSave);

function ifChangeSave() {
    //UpdateRoles();
    $("#divbackgroundLogoff").show();
    jConfirm('Yes', 'No', '', 'Are you sure you want to Save the changes?', function (ans) {
        if (!ans)
            return false;
        else {
            UpdateRoles();
        }
    });
}
```

The problem here UpdateRoles is loading everytime any change happens.
Please help if there is a better solution for this.
Thanks, NC

UPDATE:

Its .change() and not .onchange() function

Comment: I would provide a save Button and call the confirm box on button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    var ModuleSave;
    $("#Module").change(function () {
        ModuleSave = $(this).val();
        $("#Module").change(ifChangeSave);
    }
    function ifChangeSave() {
        //UpdateRoles();
        $("#divbackgroundLogoff").show();
        jConfirm('Yes', 'No', '', 'Are you sure you want to Save the changes?', function (ans) {
            if (!ans) {
                $("#Module").val(ModuleSave);
                return false;
            } else {
                UpdateRoles();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When the page is loaded, the initial change handler just enables the later change handler that asks for confirmation if it's changed a second time.

Comment: the ifChangeSave is taking the new DOM tat is loaded. well, I mean I need to save the previous values but its save the new values that are loaded. How do I tackle that?

Answer (score 1):

actually `jConfirm` three argument you have 4 given chck this **[DEMO](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/)**

```
jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
    jAlert('Confirmed: ' + r, 'Confirmation Results');
});
```

ok, so like this way to try

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var target = e.target;

    if (!$(target).is('#formlabel') && !$(target).parents().is('#roledef')) {
       ifChangeSave();
    }
});
```

try this way

```
$('#roledef').on('click',function(e) {
     // Do your work
});

$('#Module').change(function(event) { 
    event.stopPropagation();
    // Dow your work
});
```

Comment: Problem is not with "how to display the confirm box" , problem is "Wen to display the confirm box"